# Mac VNC client (for controlling Mac Mini remotely)?

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec, remote-desktop, vnc

I recently got a Mac mini as both a [media centre](https://superuser.com/questions/32885/what-do-you-have-for-a-home-server-for-multimedia/32940#32940) and a desktop computer. I'd like control it remotely, over wifi, using my MacBook.

I have the impression that what's basically needed is to enable Screen Sharing (in System Preferences -> Sharing) on the Mini, and a VNC client program on the laptop. If that is correct, **which (preferably free) VNC client is best suited for this job**? Anything else I should know?

---

**Update**: While the [OS X built-in VNC client](https://superuser.com/a/32012/2984) is the quickest solution, [JollysFastVNC](https://superuser.com/questions/32006/mac-vnc-client-for-controlling-mac-mini-remotely/32018#32018) and [Chicken of the VNC](https://superuser.com/questions/32006/mac-vnc-client-for-controlling-mac-mini-remotely/32008#32008) seem strong options too. CotVNC clearly has the best keyboard "immersion", while JollysFastVNC seemed smoother in some other ways and is more actively developed.

For a future reader looking for a Mac VNC client, I suggest you try out the 3 top options below and pick the one that suits you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Macs come with a VNC client; it’s in /System/Library/CoreServices/Screen Sharing.

Or use Finder’s Go > Connect to Server… in the menu bar (or press ⌘K) and enter vnc:// and the address of the remote Mac mini.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that! It works nicely, although I'm wondering how to change the virtual desktop... and in general how to direct keyboard shortcuts to the remote machine?

Comment: i use Screen Sharning all the time for the same reason.  Also, in Finder, in the SHARED dropdown on the left panel, find your mini there and you can click on 'Share Screen.'

Comment: I usually use "akf" approach with other macs in my house. On my media centre mini I usually change the backdrop image so I know where I am at.

The podcast http://www.maccast.com/2009/04/13/maccast-20090413/ has a good discussion on using your mini as a media center.

Answer (score 8):

[Chicken of the VNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/) is what I use.

Comment: I also like this one. *All* keyboard combinations (Cmd+Tab etc) worked with this, and that auto-scrolling is perhaps even better than JollysFastVNC's smart zoom. (More evaluation needed before I can decide which client I'll go with...)

Comment: There's one annoying thing for a new user though: it's hard to figure out how to exit Full-screen mode. It's Ctrl+Option+Cmd+`, but on my Finnish keyboard that doesn't work, and it's apparently *impossible* — had to go to the VNC server icon and disconnect the client altogether. Tons of people have been caught with the same problem: http://perendinate.com/2007/04/07/exiting-full-screen-mode-on-chicken-of-the-vnc/ I changed the shortcut to be the same as JollysFastVNC default, Ctrl+Cmd+Esc.

Comment: Just to mention, there's been no new release of COTVNC since Jan 2006, so if active development is of interest this may be an issue...

Comment: I like Chicken, but I agree with Jonik... that key combination for exiting full screen is kind of insane.  It's a character that looks exactly like a regular apostrophe most of the time when displayed, so it took about 15 minutes of googling around on my phone with my laptop disabled before I finally figured out they meant the back tick...

Answer (score 6):

[JollysFastVNC](http://www.jinx.de/JollysFastVNC.html) is by far my prefered client. It is fast, has a built in SSH tunnel mapper, cool screen zoom if your client screen is much smaller than server machine) lots of options for more complete keyboard immersion, which hopefully should solve your screen sharing problems...

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Compared to the built-in VNC client, I especially like the full-screen mode and the "smart zoom" feature you mentioned — useful as my Mini is connected to a 1600x1200 display while the MacBook only does 1280x800.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/home.asp?hp=2). You can use it from any computer and you only have to install software on the computer you control. It's also free, which is always nice.

Comment: For the record, Mac specific info here: https://secure.logmein.com/products/free/mac/.  Thanks — right now I just want a VNC client for controlling the Mini while at home, so I'm not too eager with their required registration etc. But I might check it out later, if I ever want to access my computers from anywhere in the world.

Comment: OK, sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

Tao of Mac has a [VNC posting](http://the.taoofmac.com/space/VNC).
There is also [JollysFastVNC](http://www.jinx.de/JollysFastVNC.html).
And, wikiHow: [How to Setup VNC on Mac OS X](http://www.wikihow.com/Setup-VNC-on-Mac-OS-X)

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any experiences of the different clients? Can you recommend JollysFastVNC?

Comment: @jonik, no first hand experience -- which is why I left out the recommendations.