# Snow Leopard VNC client

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, software-rec, vnc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mac VNC client for controlling Mac Mini remotely?](https://superuser.com/questions/32006/mac-vnc-client-for-controlling-mac-mini-remotely)

I know how to VNC into other computers from a Windows and Linux system, but have never done it with a Mac before.  I have a MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard.  How can I use VNC on here?

Comment: E.g. my earlier question http://superuser.com/questions/32006/mac-vnc-client-for-controlling-mac-mini-remotely covers Mac VNC clients pretty well.

Answer (score 8):

Download [Chicken of the VNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/) (VNC Client Mac OS X)

Or you can use the native VNC client of Snow Leopard :

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> in finder :

[image]

If the vnc server is not running on the standart port (5900) enter the address as follows:

```
vnc://servernameorip:port
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer [JollysFastVNC](http://www.jinx.de/JollysFastVNC.html) for anything VNC related and [CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/) for RDP on Windows boxes.

[image: JollysFastVNC]

Comment: CoRD seems to be a nice tool ! I don't know much about Windows RDP... Does CoRD support the same as Remote Desktop Connection for Mac (http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/remote-desktop/default.mspx) ?

Comment: CoRD is awesome +1 !

Comment: Yes I believe it does, but in a slick native way.